# Google Chrome Extension serial port on website

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, serial-port

I use chrome.serial to communicate with device on COM port and i need provide basic api for javascript on my web-site. First try was with content_script + messaging, but i can't use `serial` permission with `content_script` because one of them require extension to be packaged app, and another to be extension. Can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can solve this by a [`chrome extension`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) to support [**Content Scripts**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) and [`packaged app`](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html) for [**serial port communication**](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial.html) with [External Message Communication](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-connect)

Fetch your Extension Id's using [management API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#method-getAll) and establish [connection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-connect) for single message [communication](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-sendMessage).

[**On Message External**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#event-onMessageExternal) is fired when a message is sent from another extension.

### References

- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- [Serial API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial.html)
- [Packaged APP](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html)
- [Chrome Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html)
- [Management API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html)
- [Extension API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html)

Comment: that's exactly what i want to avoid: two extensions instead one. but if it only way, i do it. Thanks! But it seems i can't use `chrome.extension` inside packaged app, it's `undefined`

Comment: After some investigation, this is the only way to do it in chrome. You've to create an app and a extension. The extension only contains a content_script, and there, some listener (I put and EventListener) that will forward received data to the app using chrome.runtime.sendMessage. The app will be waiting with chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal listener, and when data arrives, will open a serial port and send data.
I've to say that in linux the app works great, but in windows, sometimes the port doesn't respond :S I'm debugging this, and when solved, I plan to upload something to github ;)

Comment: @sdespont well, I developed a custom extension and addon for google chrome. I worked ok in linux pcs, but in windows sometimes the port didn't close and then you had to restart the browser :S I can upload the code to github if you're interested ;)

Comment: @sucotronic Thanks for your answer. Ok, it is visibly not stable on Windows.

Comment: @sucotronic I have a feeling that it's not true. An app can be ["externally_connectable"](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/externally_connectable) from a web site, so a content script / extension are not needed, a site can talk to an app directly as long as it is set in the manifest beforehand.

Comment: @xan the extension is needed in order to handle the serial port connection and data reading/writing. My goal was to speak to the serial port directly from javascript without developing a custom app or complex extension.

Comment: @sucotronic An extension cannot communicate with the serial port anyway, you need a Chrome App for that. With that in mind, I'm saying that one does not need the extension.

Comment: @xan now I see your point (so much time since I did this :P). You're in reason, with that setting on the manifest, the extension isn't neccesary ;)

Answer (score 1):

Update to this thread, they may use Web Serial to communicate using web to serial port.

https://chromestatus.com/feature/6577673212002304
https://web.dev/serial/

Answer (score -1):

index.html

```
<button>Connect</button>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

main.js

```
var connectionId;

/* Converts a string to UTF-8 encoding in a Uint8Array; returns the array */

var str2ab = function(str) {
   var encodedString = unescape(encodeURIComponent(str));
   var bytes = new Uint8Array(encodedString.length);
   for (var i = 0; i < encodedString.length; ++i) {
      bytes[i] = encodedString.charCodeAt(i);
   }
   return bytes.buffer;
};

var options = {
  'bitrate': 115200,
  'dataBits': 'eight',
  'parityBit': 'no',
  'stopBits': 'one'
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', btnSend);
  chrome.serial.connect('COM3', options, function(info) {
    connectionId = info.connectionId;
    console.log("Connection established.");
  });
});

var btnSend = function() {
  var msg = "hello printer 123456\n";
  chrome.serial.send(connectionId, str2ab(msg), function() {} );
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Printer at COM3 test",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": ["serial"],
  "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon_16.png",
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["launch.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

launch.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    id: "mainwin",
    innerBounds: {
      width: 320,
      height: 240
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is not on a webpage, but a chrome app (not an answer on the question). I tried to run it, to do that, read step 4: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started_simple