# Library to do a bluetooth dialer

Tags: python, .net, dll, bluetooth

I need to develop a windows (and preferably also linux) program to dial a number in a bluetooth connected phone. I've doing some research, and only have found these two programs:

- [Bluetooth PC dialer](http://blueshareware.com/bluetooth_pc_dialer.asp): windows only program to input phone numbers an dial them with a click
- [HFP for Linux](http://nohands.sourceforge.net/index.html): linux only software (library+program) to use the pc as a hands free device

First approach was to think about AT commands, but I haven't succeed with that. ¿Does anybody know (or have experience) about which library to use to do only remote dial over bluetooth?

Update 9/5/2013: found [some more info](http://homepages.ius.edu/RWISMAN/C490/html/PythonandBluetooth.htm), but not able to work with it.

Comment: http://32feet.codeplex.com/

Comment: i4v thanks for url, but I've not been able to found any helpful info in there :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I take the approach of using the operative system tools to stablish a serial connection to the device, and then use chrome app+extension ([based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154123/google-chrome-extension-serial-port-on-website/14154715#14154715)) to send AT commands from javascript app, avoiding to code multi-platform app.