# Chrome Extension w/ Serial and Page Action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, serial-port, google-chrome-app

Currently, I have created a Chrome App that gets data from a serial connection using the Chrome App Serial API. My goal is to inject this data into a web page. I know this is capable with Chrome Extensions, but the issue there is that Chrome Extensions aren't capable of accessing the serial data on it's own. I also would like to use an Extension instead of an App because the Chrome Apps aren't going to be supported starting this year.

The only option I could think of is to use a Chrome App to get the serial data, send the data to an Extension, and then inject the data into a web page. This is definitely not preferable though. Besides the Chrome Apps not being supported, except for Chrome OS, I wouldn't like to have to have a user download the extension and the app just to implement this.

My preferred method would to have an Extension access the serial devices. Is this possible and/or is it going to possible in the future? If not, why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found here in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154123) that you can use chrome extension with serial data with the use of [`content scripts`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and [`package app`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps). According to this, you can fetch your Extension Id's by using  the management API and establish a connection for single message communication.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, however this is the approach of connecting the App to an Extension and then to the page. I do think this is the only way to do it. I'm going to look into node serialport for the extension. That way I can stop using the App since they're getting deprecated.