# Comunicate a Chrome App with a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to display data received from a serial port in a website (display that data in an Chrome app doesn't satisfy the requeriments).

All i know about Chrome apps, extensions, etc. i learned it between yesterday and today, so i'm pretty new on that.

For what i understand about all this, trough reading the official documentation, is that i need to create both an extension and an app.

So i have to get the serial port data in the app, and then pass it to a extension with a contentScript and with that content script i display the data on the DOM.

The problem i'm facing right now and i'm stuck in is that i can't figure how to pass data from an app to a extension.

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14154715/5854695) tells me about a method called OnMessageExternal, but i see in the documentation that it is not available for extension.

So if anyone know how to send an message from a Chrome App to a Chrome Extension, please help me, i will be very grateful :)

Comment: Where do you see onMessageExternal is unavailable? It is - see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessageExternal). It's available in a [background page script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) which can send a message to your content script.

Comment: wOxxOm Thank you very much. I will be reading about background page script now.

Comment: @wOxxOm It worked for me, thank you very much. You saved my life :)